# Text in table-cell on top and bottom

Tags: css, html-table, tablelayout, text-align

I got the following setup:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">Cell 1 [fixed width]</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 3 [fixed width]</div>
</div>
```

with this css:

```
.table {
     display: table-cell;
     width: 100%;
}
.cell {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Now I want to have some text in *Cell 3*. A bit of text which should be at the bottom of the cell. With *vertical-align* I could do this easily but I got another line which should stay at the middle or top of the cell. How can I do this? I tried some things with height settings but these have no effect on the cell. And line-height wouldn't work either because the height is not fixed.

Comment: using position absolute you can solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out below answer: 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8cfs4j66/4/)

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell1">Cell 1 [fixed width]</div>

    <div class="cell2">Cell 2</div>

    <div class="cell3">Cell 3 [fixed width] <div class="bot_txt">bottom text</div></div>
</div>


.table {
     display: table;
     width: 100%;
}
.cell1 {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
     width: 33%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
}
.cell2 {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
     width: 33%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:green;
}
.cell3 {
    background-color:yellow;
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: top;
     width: 33%;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
}
.bot_txt {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: `position:relative;` on .cell3 did the job! Only `position:absolute;` like recommended by Arun had no effect.

Comment: if you want to use position:absolute;, then you need to specify position for it's parent element as well

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">Cell 1 [fixed width]</div>
  <div class="cell">Cell 2</div>
  <div class="cell">Cell 3 [fixed width]
    <br>additional line</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, see correct answer on what i tried to achieve. I wanted to the text to be at the bottom most and the top most, not just above each others.